# Returning a custom class in WCF

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, custom-object

I created WCF service that returns a custom object called XmlElementTreeNode. This is what the object looks like:

```
[DataContract]
public class XmlElementTreeNode
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Attributes { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<XmlElementTreeNode> Children { get; set; }

    public XmlElementTreeNode() { }
}
```

I am able to successfully create a heirarchy of these nodes with this method:

```
[OperationContract]
public XmlElementTreeNode GetTreeView(string initialSchemaUri)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(initialSchemaUri, UriKind.Absolute);
    XPathSorter sorter = new XPathSorter(uri);
    XmlElementTreeNode theNode = sorter.rootTreeNode;
    return theNode;
}
```

But the error I get back is:

```
CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

at this method in Reference.cs:

```
public SilverlightApplication.SchemaServiceReference.XmlElementTreeNode EndGetTreeView(System.IAsyncResult result)
{
    object[] _args = new object[0];
    SilverlightApplication.SchemaServiceReference.XmlElementTreeNode _result = ((SilverlightApplication.SchemaServiceReference.XmlElementTreeNode)(base.EndInvoke("GetTreeView", _args, result)));
    return _result;
}
```

I rewrote the service to return `theNode.Name` and `theNode.Attributes` instead. Both of those worked. I also rewrote the service to return `theNode.Children` and I get the same exact error.

So, when I get this error, I never reach this code in Silverlight, because the service did not "finish."

```
void service_GetTreeViewCompleted(object sender, GetTreeViewCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlElementTreeNode rootNode = e.Result;
}
```

However, I found this interesting. I changed `return theNode` to `return theNode.Children[0]`. So, I still am returning an XmlElementTreeNode object to Silverlight. When I did this, I was able to reach the `service_GetTreeViewCompleted` method and access my tree of nodes (although only starting from the first child of the root node). I think it's strange that this worked, but not the "root" node (the original `theNode` variable).

Anyone have any ideas how I can return my `theNode` variable? I'm completely new to WCF, so maybe there is some other way to go about returning my complex custom object properly that I am not aware of.

**Update 1**

My `XmlElementTreeNode` object represents an xml element as defined by an xsd document. The generated heiarchy of `XmlElementTreeNodes` represent all the possible elements that could be created in an XML file thati validated against the XSD uri being passed into my service. It just so happens that the first element of `theNode.Children` represents only a small tree of nodes. However, I tried to return `theNode.Children[1]`, which has thousands of sub-nodes, and I get the same error. So, I think the problem is that the size of the entire `theNode` object is simply too big.

I tried editing my binding as follows in Web.config:

```
    <binding name="SilverlightApplication.Web.SchemaService.customBinding0">
      <textMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
```

But, even with those huge values, I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "NotFound" error is a big issue in Silverlight because it essentially means that "something went wrong" - by default all non-200 responses from the service are translated into a 404 (Not Found) by the SL networking layer, and no further information is given to the program. A few things you can do:

- Look at a network capture tool (such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)) to see the exact response that the server is returning to the client.
- If the response is something like 500 (Internal Server Error), [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on the server side and the trace should contain an exception which explains the error.

There are some documentations about debugging WCF services in SL. There's a good video (25 minutes long) at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2010/09/23/debugging-wcf-services-in-silverlight.aspx, and there's a MSDN page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197938(v=VS.95).aspx with some good information as well.

Comment: Using Fiddler, I got this response for my service: "ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request." I will also look at enabling tracing.

Comment: The video was very helpful. However, I tried EVERYTHING on that video and only had one case where I had any type of different debugging result. When I updated my service in  ServicesReferences.ClientConfig to use a relative path (`../SchemaService.svc` instead of `http://localhost:12345/SchemaService.svc`), I get back TimeoutException was unhandled by user codeThe remote server returned an error: NotFound in Visual Studio. But nothing extra came up in Fiddler, or ViewDetail -> InnerException / StackTrace etc..

Comment: The "ReadResponse() failed: the server did not return a response" - is the request actually getting to the server? As for nothing being shown when using http://localhost..., IIRC fiddler doesn't catch requests sent to *localhost*, you'd need to send it to the machine name (and also open the SL page using the machine name instead of localhost, to prevent cross-domain issues)

Comment: Another thing to try: create a non-Silverlight (i.e., a "normal") WCF client to talk to this service, this may help in eliminating some SL-specific issues with the communication.

Answer (score 1):

As expected, the problem is that my returned object is too big. I found out that I needed to add the following line to my Web.config:

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
```

In context with the rest of the Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
   ...
```